# Issue with the positionning of view with Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have an issue with a xml layout inside my application on Android Studio. 
On Android Studio it shows me something that I want exactly but when I run the application the layout is definitely not what I want. Everything is messed and I don't understand why.

I have been googling and looking inside the forum for awhile but I have found nothing so far. I have spent a lot of time on android developers tutorial and documentation, but still stuck.

So here is my xml file with what Android Studio shows me the layout i want on the design view :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:id="@+id/ll_printer_name">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name_printer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Printer 1"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_press_to_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_name_printer"
        android:text="press to test"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Regular"
        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
        android:textSize="6sp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_press_to_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[Here is the picture of the design view on Studio Android. It is as I want to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEdO.png)

And when I run the app, it is like this :

[What I have after running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKzXe.png)

The textView "Press to test" is not where I want, it is up to the "Printer 1" even if I have written this on the XML file :

```
android:layout_below="@id/tv_name_printer"
```

If anyone can help, I am stuck for awhile. 
Thanks in advance !!

**Edit** (especially for  tanni tanna) : here some part of the code (the code is very long) using this layout for creating the fragment that displays the view that is not as I want :

So when we click on a button, this methods is called. This method uses the layout showed above (id of the layout :item_printer_name)

```
 private ViewGroup llPrinterList; 


 private void searchPrinters(){
    PrinterSearcher.searchPrintersListener listener = new PrinterSearcher.searchPrintersListener() {
        @Override
        public void printersFound(List<Printer> printers) {
            for(Printer p : printers){
                View llPrinterName = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_printer_name, null);
                llPrinterList.addView(llPrinterName);
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name_printer);
                t.setText(p.getName());
            }
        }
    };
 PrinterSearcher.searchPrinters(listener, this, getActivity());
}
```

PrinterSearcher is a class used to find the printer inside a network. We don't really need to know much about it. 
searchPrintersListener is an interface inside this class. This interface has just one method : printersFound

But I have also found out something strange : when I do this (I have deleted the space, but actually I need this space) inside my layout it does more or less what I want :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:id="@+id/ll_printer_name">
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_name_printer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Printer 1"
       android:textSize="10sp"
       android:textAllCaps="true"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Bold"
       android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_press_to_test"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_printer"
      android:text="press to test"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textAllCaps="true"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Regular"
      android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
      android:textSize="6sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

But when I change for the textView "press to test" :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to :

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

it does the same thing as before

Answer (score 0):

issue android:layout_below="@id/tv_name_printer"
use below in the 2nd TextVIew

```
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_printer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_printer_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name_printer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Printer 1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_press_to_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_printer"
    android:text="press to test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="6sp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_press_to_test" />
```

Edit : This is the result 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingLeft="10sp"
android:paddingRight="10sp"
android:id="@+id/ll_printer_name">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name_printer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Printer 1"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_press_to_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_name_printer"
    android:text="press to test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="6sp" />

<Space
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_press_to_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```